# How to solve this system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

How to solve the following system of equations (If it is possible, I am seeking exact solutions)

````
NN=3;
CC=Array[c, {NN, NN}];
System={{1.27413 + 
    1.22474 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
       0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
    3.65148 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
       0.142026 c[3., 2.]) - 
    0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
       7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
    6. (0.780452 - 
       0.334719 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 3.])) - 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) (0.219548 + 
       0.334719 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.142026 c[3., 2.]) - 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 3.])) + 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) + 
    7.66938 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
       0.142026 c[3., 3.]) + 
    3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 1.]) + 
       0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 3.])) - 
    1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
       0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 0., 
  0.600909 + 
    1.22474 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
       0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
    0.273861 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
       7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
    6. (0.397285 + 
       0.273861 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.142026 c[3., 2.]) - 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) (0.602715 - 
       0.273861 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) - 
    6.27495 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
       0.142026 c[3., 3.]) - 
    1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
       0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 0., 
  0.0432262 + 
    1.22474 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
       0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
    3.65148 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
       0.142026 c[3., 2.]) - 
    0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
       7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
    6. (0.258847 - 
       0.334719 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.142026 c[3., 2.]) - 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 3.])) - 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) (0.741153 + 
       0.334719 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 3.])) + 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) + 
    7.66938 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
       0.142026 c[3., 3.]) - 
    3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 1.]) + 
       0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 3.])) - 
    1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
       0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 
   0.}, {1.15114 + 
    1.22474 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
       0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
    0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) - 
    3.65148 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
       0.167848 c[3., 2.]) - 
    6. (0.81314 - 
       0.334719 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 3.])) - 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) (0.18686 + 
       0.334719 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.167848 c[3., 2.]) - 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 3.])) + 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) + 
    3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 6.27495 c[3., 1.]) + 
       0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 6.27495 c[3., 3.])) - 
    1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 6.27495 c[3., 1.]) - 
       0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 6.27495 c[3., 3.])) + 
    7.66938 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
       0.167848 c[3., 3.]) == 0., 
  0.779707 + 
    1.22474 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
       0.167848 c[3., 1.]) + 
    0.273861 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) - 
    6. (0.399932 + 
       0.273861 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.167848 c[3., 2.]) - 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) (0.600068 - 
       0.273861 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) - 
    1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 6.27495 c[3., 1.]) - 
       0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 6.27495 c[3., 3.])) - 
    6.27495 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
       0.167848 c[3., 3.]) == 0., 
  0.106284 + 
    1.22474 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
       0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
    0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) + 
    3.65148 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
       0.167848 c[3., 2.]) - 
    6. (0.215937 - 
       0.334719 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.167848 c[3., 2.]) - 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 3.])) - 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) (0.784063 + 
       0.334719 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 3.])) + 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) - 
    3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 6.27495 c[3., 1.]) + 
       0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 6.27495 c[3., 3.])) - 
    1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 6.27495 c[3., 1.]) - 
       0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 6.27495 c[3., 3.])) + 
    7.66938 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
       0.167848 c[3., 3.]) == 
   0.}, {1.05418 + 
    1.22474 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
       0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
    3.65148 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
       0.193671 c[3., 2.]) - 
    0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
       7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
    6. (0.845828 - 
       0.334719 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 3.])) - 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) (0.154172 + 
       0.334719 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.193671 c[3., 2.]) - 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 3.])) + 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) + 
    7.66938 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
       0.193671 c[3., 3.]) + 
    3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] + 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 1.]) + 
       0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] + 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 3.])) - 
    1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] + 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
       0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] + 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 0., 
  0.984521 + 
    1.22474 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
       0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
    0.273861 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
       7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
    6. (0.402578 + 
       0.273861 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.193671 c[3., 2.]) - 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) (0.597422 - 
       0.273861 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) - 
    6.27495 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
       0.193671 c[3., 3.]) - 
    1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] + 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
       0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] + 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 0., 
  0.195358 + 
    1.22474 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
       0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
    3.65148 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
       0.193671 c[3., 2.]) - 
    0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
       7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
    6. (0.173028 - 
       0.334719 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.193671 c[3., 2.]) - 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 3.])) - 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) (0.826972 + 
       0.334719 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
          0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
       3.65148 (0.111803 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
          0.0636469 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 3.])) + 
       1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
          0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
          1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
             0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) + 
    7.66938 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
       0.193671 c[3., 3.]) - 
    3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] + 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 1.]) + 
       0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] + 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 3.])) - 
    1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] + 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
       0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
       1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] + 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
          7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 0.}};

Solve[System// Flatten, Flatten[CC]]
```
````

Comment: What have you tried?  And what, pray tell, is `c`?

Comment: For starters, define `System2 = System /. c[i_, j_] :> c[Round[i], Round[j]]` so that the arguments of `c` are integers instead of floating-point numbers.

Comment: It would probably help if you posted more information as to where these equations come from. There is a lot of structure in these equations, especially in the quadratic coefficients; knowing more about where this structure comes from would help in finding good solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NN = 3;
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html), [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html), and [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) `System`

```
System = {{1.27413 + 
        1.22474 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
           0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
        3.65148 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
           0.142026 c[3., 2.]) - 
        0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
           7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
        6. (0.780452 - 
           0.334719 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 3.])) - 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) (0.219548 + 
           0.334719 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.142026 c[3., 2.]) - 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 3.])) + 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) + 
        7.66938 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
           0.142026 c[3., 3.]) + 
        3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 1.]) + 
           0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 3.])) - 
        1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
           0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 0., 
      0.600909 + 
        1.22474 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
           0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
        0.273861 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
           7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
        6. (0.397285 + 
           0.273861 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.142026 c[3., 2.]) - 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) (0.602715 - 
           0.273861 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) - 
        6.27495 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
           0.142026 c[3., 3.]) - 
        1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
           0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 0., 
      0.0432262 + 
        1.22474 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
           0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
        3.65148 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
           0.142026 c[3., 2.]) - 
        0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
           7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
        6. (0.258847 - 
           0.334719 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.142026 c[3., 2.]) - 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 3.])) - 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) (0.741153 + 
           0.334719 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 3.])) + 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0226805 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0226805 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.142026 c[3., 3.]))) + 
        7.66938 (0.0226805 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
           0.142026 c[3., 3.]) - 
        3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 1.]) + 
           0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 3.])) - 
        1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
           0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 
       0.}, {1.15114 + 
        1.22474 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
           0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
        0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) - 
        3.65148 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
           0.167848 c[3., 2.]) - 
        6. (0.81314 - 
           0.334719 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 3.])) - 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) (0.18686 + 
           0.334719 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.167848 c[3., 2.]) - 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 3.])) + 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) + 
        3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 6.27495 c[3., 1.]) + 
           0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 6.27495 c[3., 3.])) - 
        1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 6.27495 c[3., 1.]) - 
           0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 6.27495 c[3., 3.])) + 
        7.66938 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
           0.167848 c[3., 3.]) == 0., 
      0.779707 + 
        1.22474 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
           0.167848 c[3., 1.]) + 
        0.273861 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) - 
        6. (0.399932 + 
           0.273861 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.167848 c[3., 2.]) - 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) (0.600068 - 
           0.273861 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) - 
        1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 6.27495 c[3., 1.]) - 
           0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 6.27495 c[3., 3.])) - 
        6.27495 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
           0.167848 c[3., 3.]) == 0., 
      0.106284 + 
        1.22474 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
           0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
        0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) + 
        3.65148 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
           0.167848 c[3., 2.]) - 
        6. (0.215937 - 
           0.334719 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.167848 c[3., 2.]) - 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 3.])) - 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) (0.784063 + 
           0.334719 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 3.])) + 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.0680414 c[1., 1.] - 0.13524 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.0680414 c[1., 2.] - 0.13524 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.167848 c[3., 3.]))) - 
        3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 6.27495 c[3., 1.]) + 
           0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 6.27495 c[3., 3.])) - 
        1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] - 6.27495 c[3., 1.]) - 
           0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] - 6.27495 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] - 6.27495 c[3., 3.])) + 
        7.66938 (0.0680414 c[1., 3.] - 0.13524 c[2., 3.] + 
           0.167848 c[3., 3.]) == 
       0.}, {1.05418 + 
        1.22474 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
           0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
        3.65148 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
           0.193671 c[3., 2.]) - 
        0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
           7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
        6. (0.845828 - 
           0.334719 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 3.])) - 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) (0.154172 + 
           0.334719 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.193671 c[3., 2.]) - 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 3.])) + 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) + 
        7.66938 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
           0.193671 c[3., 3.]) + 
        3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] + 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 1.]) + 
           0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] + 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 3.])) - 
        1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] + 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
           0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] + 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 0., 
      0.984521 + 
        1.22474 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
           0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
        0.273861 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
           7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
        6. (0.402578 + 
           0.273861 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.193671 c[3., 2.]) - 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) (0.597422 - 
           0.273861 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) - 
        6.27495 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
           0.193671 c[3., 3.]) - 
        1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] + 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
           0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] + 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 0., 
      0.195358 + 
        1.22474 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
           0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
        3.65148 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
           0.193671 c[3., 2.]) - 
        0.334719 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
           7.66938 c[3., 2.]) - 
        6. (0.173028 - 
           0.334719 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.193671 c[3., 2.]) - 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 3.])) - 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) (0.826972 + 
           0.334719 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
              0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
           3.65148 (0.111803 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 1.]) + 
              0.0636469 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 3.])) + 
           1.22474 (0.5 (0.113402 c[1., 1.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 1.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 1.]) - 
              0.770201 (0.113402 c[1., 2.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 2.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 2.]) + 
              1.23343 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
                 0.193671 c[3., 3.]))) + 
        7.66938 (0.113402 c[1., 3.] - 0.0676201 c[2., 3.] + 
           0.193671 c[3., 3.]) - 
        3.65148 (0.111803 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] + 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 1.]) + 
           0.0636469 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] + 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 3.])) - 
        1.22474 (0.5 (1.22474 c[1., 1.] + 3.65148 c[2., 1.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 1.]) - 
           0.770201 (1.22474 c[1., 2.] + 3.65148 c[2., 2.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 2.]) + 
           1.23343 (1.22474 c[1., 3.] + 3.65148 c[2., 3.] + 
              7.66938 c[3., 3.])) == 0.}} // Rationalize[#, 0] & // 
   Simplify // Flatten;
```

`Flatten` the array of coefficients

```
CC = Array[c, {NN, NN}] // Flatten;
```

The RHSs of the`System` are all zero

```
System[[All, -1]]

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

A numeric solution can be obtained by minimizing the sum of the squares of the LHSs of `System`

```
{min, sol} = NMinimize[Total[System[[All, 1]]^2], CC]

(* {2.16278*10^-30, {c[1, 1] -> -1.25424, c[1, 2] -> 1.67449, c[1, 3] -> 1.17733,
   c[2, 1] -> 0.190073, c[2, 2] -> 0.291208, c[2, 3] -> 0.1152, 
  c[3, 1] -> 0.0137603, c[3, 2] -> 0.0142967, c[3, 3] -> 0.00558706}} *)
```

**EDIT:** If you want greater precision, use arbitrary-precision

```
{min2, sol2} = NMinimize[Total[System[[All, 1]]^2], CC,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* {0, {c[1, 1] -> -1.2542414937153355487, c[1, 2] -> 1.6744903249942181335, 
  c[1, 3] -> 1.1773305678865958616, c[2, 1] -> 0.19007284799137451620, 
  c[2, 2] -> 0.29120752439958518851, c[2, 3] -> 0.11520029768316410111, 
  c[3, 1] -> 0.013760271744735137805, c[3, 2] -> 0.014296715720958218916, 
  c[3, 3] -> 0.0055870573904598545272}} *)

Max@Abs[System[[All, 1]] /. sol2]

(* 0.*10^-19 *)

System /. sol2

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that exact solutions are not possible for this question. Can we guess the upper bound for your method?

Comment: The maximum absolute error for the LHSs is `Max@Abs[System[[All, 1]] /. sol]` or approximately `7*10^-16` Since your system is defined with machine precision numbers, there are no **exact** solutions.